# Problems with deserializing FieldInfos and PropertyInfos when using Newtonsoft.Json libraries

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize and deserialize FieldInfo and PropertyInfos, and I am getting this error, which I dont understand, nor do I know how to fix or change what I am doing to fix this: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type System.Reflection.FieldInfo. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.`

The basis of what I am trying to do is serialize and deserialize a class called AutoLType that looks like this:

```
public class AutoLType
{
    public static implicit operator AutoSType(AutoLType l)
    {
        if (l.PropertyOrField == PropOrField.Field)
        {
            return new AutoSType(l.Field, l.Attribute, AutoSType.PropOrField.Field);
        }
        else
        {
            return new AutoSType(l.Property, l.Attribute, AutoSType.PropOrField.Prop);
        }
    }

    public enum PropOrField
    {
        Prop,
        Field
    }

    public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
    public FieldInfo Field { get; set; }
    public AutoLoad Attribute { get; set; }
    public PropOrField PropertyOrField { get; set; }
        
    public AutoLType(object pOrF, AutoLoad attr, PropOrField propOrField)
    {
        if (pOrF is PropertyInfo)
        {
            Property = (PropertyInfo)pOrF;
        }
        else if(pOrF is FieldInfo)
        {
            Field = (FieldInfo)pOrF;
        }
        Attribute = attr;
        PropertyOrField = propOrField;
    }
}
```

```
public AutoLType Load(AutoLType autoLTypeToLoad)
{
    AutoLType a = null;
    try
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + autoLTypeToLoad.Attribute.FilePath;
        string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AutoLType>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Let me know if you need to see the AutoLoad class, but it isnt giving any problems right now.

Comment: You can't deserialize those types. If they refer to properties or fields you could use the name of the property or field instead, and the name of the type it returns if needed. It doesn't sound like a thing that we'd normally want to do, but if you need to, that would be a workable approach.

Comment: @ScottHannen I am trying to get the value that the FieldInfo and PropertyInfo, how can I store that as well? Just a object?

Comment: Try to deserialize  without the enum, it's the problem. You can maybe store the data without the enum and latter access as a enum/or save the data you need in a enum class.